# Out of local stack error in Prolog route planner

Tags: list, recursion, prolog

I am trying to write Prolog route planner between towns. Here's my code:

```
road(meath,dublin,5). 
road(dublin,kildare,9).
road(kildare,wicklow,7).
road(wicklow,wexford,10).

/*Rules:*/
route(X,Y,[H|_ ],N) :-
   road(H,Y,_),
   routen(X,Y,N1),
   N is N1.
route(X,Y,[H|T],N) :-
   road(X,H,_ ),
   routen(X,Y,N1), 
   N is N1,
   route(H,Y,T,_),
   !.
route(X,Y,[],N) :-
   road(X,Y,N1),
   N is N1.

routen(X,Y,N) :-
   road(X,Y,N).
routen(X,Y,N) :-
   road(X,Z,N1),
   road(Z,Y,N2),
   N is N1+N2.
routen(X,Y,N) :-
   routen(X,Z,N1),
   routen(Z,Y,N2),
   N is N1+N2,
   !.
```

The predicate `road` has the two towns and the distance between them. The rule `route` finds the list of towns between `X` and `Y` and `routen` finds the overall distance between two towns.

When I run `route`, it sometimes works and other times I get a `ERROR: Out of local stack`.

Example:

```
?- route(meath,wexford,[dublin,kildare,wicklow],31).
true. 

?- route(meath,wexford,[dublin,kildare,wicklow],30).
false.

?- route(meath,kerry,[dublin,kildare,wicklow],31).
ERROR: Out of local stack
```

The last one should return `false`, as a route between `meath` and `kerry` doesn't exist. Does anyone know why I am getting an error?

Answer (score 1):

Rules in Prolog are LEFT RECURSIVE.
In you last rule you did:

```
routen(X,Y,N) :- routen(X,Z,N1),routen(Z,Y,N2),N is N1+N2,!.
```

wich it makes your program try the rule **routen(X,Z,N1)** infinite times. This means that at one point the stack will be full.

Here what happens:

1. find a route from meath to kerry.
2. It doens't exist a direct road between the cities: try to find another intermediate city. It find meath-dublin.
3. Then it try dublin-kerry. But, again, it doens't exist a direct road between the cities: try to find another intermediate city. It find dublin-kildare. And so on.
4. Finally it arrives to find micklow-wexford. So The route found so far is: meath-dublin-kildare-wicklow-wexford.
5. Now it try for wexford-kerry with the first

   ```
   route(X,Y,[H|_ ],N) :- road(H,Y,_),routen(X,Y,N1), N is N1.
   ```

   It satisfy the first one

   ```
   road(H,Y,_)
   ```

   then it reduces

   ```
   routen(X,Y,N1), N is N1.
   ```

   5.1 It tries with the first rule

   ```
   routen(wexford,kerry,N) :- road(wexford,kerry,N).
   ```

   that fails, cause doesn't exist a direct road between them. So it call:

   ```
   routen(wexford,kerry,N) :- road(wexford,Z,N1),road(Z,kerry,N2),N is N1+N2.
   ```

   which fails cause it can't satify

   ```
   road(wexford,Z,N1).
   ```

   At the end, it tries with the last rule

   ```
   routen(wexford,kerry,N) :- routen(wexford,Z,N1),routen(Z,kerry,N2),N is N1+N2,!.
   ```

   So it reduces

   ```
   routen(wexford,Z,N1),routen(Z,kerry,N2),N is N1+N2,!.
   ```
6. It tries to satisfy the first one

   ```
   routen(wexford,Z,N1).
   ```

   with

   ```
   routen(X,Y,N) :- road(X,Y,N).
   routen(X,Y,N) :- road(X,Z,N1),road(Z,Y,N2),N is N1+N2.
   routen(X,Y,N) :- routen(X,Z,N1),routen(Z,Y,N2),N is N1+N2,!.
   ```

   respectively, with

   ```
   X=wexford
   Z=DG51_  % or something like that. That is, an not instantiated variable
   ```

   and repeat the step 5.1

As you can see, it will never find the city "kerry" and it fall in an infinite loop.

Here the new code:

```
road(meath,dublin,5). 
road(dublin,kildare,9).
road(kildare,wicklow,7).
road(wicklow,wexford,10).

/*Rules:*/

route(X,Y,[H|_ ],N) :- routen(X,Y,N),!.
%route(X,Y,[H|T],N) :- road(X,H,_ ),routen(X,Y,N1), N is N1, route(H,Y,T,_).
route(X,Y,[],N) :- road(X,Y,N1), N is N1.
routen(X,Y,N) :- road(X,Y,N).
%routen(X,Y,N) :- road(X,Z,N1),road(Z,Y,N2),N is N1+N2.
routen(X,Y,N) :- road(X,Z,N1),routen(Z,Y,N2),N is N1+N2.
```

Notice that at the last rule I put

```
road(X,Z,N1)
```

before

```
routen(Z,Y,N2)
```

So, if the first clause of that body fails, you'll never fall in a loop with the second one.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "Rules in Prolog are LEFT RECURSIVE." ?

Comment: The first rule that will be reduced is the first one of the body. The search is a "depth-first search" so it go on the branch to the left first.